# How to Drive a 50uA Panel Meter with a PLC Running 24v Inverted PWM Signal

Tags: voltage, resistors, pwm, plc

Full disclosure, I am not an engineer of any kind. Just an electronics enthusiast.

I have a Barth 850 micro PLC that needs to operate at 24v, and has one PWM output. I also have a 50uA panel meter that I would like to drive with the PWM pin, and adjust the PWM output via a POT connected to one of the inputs. Also, I tested the output of the PWM signal, and it is inverted. From what I've been reading, I should be able to bring that 24v signal down to something manageable for a 50uA meter by using resistors, I just don't know how to calculate that value. Any help with the math, or what resistor(s) value I should go for would be super appreciated. This is the limits of my knowledge in this area.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of "seems to be." But this is [OUT9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC714.png) from page 4/9 of doc *9021-0025-A*. Is the software behavior operating this output disclosed? ("Graphical miCon-L, Open Source‚ C‘ Programming" from the manual.)

Comment: Indeed there are some things about how the software handles PWM that aren't very clear in the documentation. But I am programming the PLC with miCon-L, so there will be a good amount of experimentation to see how it works.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how anyone can help design a circuit to drive a panel meter without this information in advance. I think I'm gathering, though, that you are turning this problem on its head, so to speak. You would like a circuit and are willing to write software so that the panel meter does what you want with the meter and circuit you are given. But there is a problem with asking the question this way. Those providing you an answer, seems to me, haven't been helpful since all they did was compute a resistor for you based on a false caricature of your needs.

Comment: What this really is... is more of a negotiation. You probably want a simpler circuit consistent with simpler software -- in short, the optimal balance of cost, work, speed, etc that gets the job done well. But this means you need to specify a lot more than you have about what you can do in software, what the information source and behavior actually is, and what you need to achieve, finally, at the meter that will be read out by someone for some purpose. Only then can domain experts work with each other to factor out a truly good solution here. (My opinion only.)

Comment: I do think a very simple circuit can be achieved here. Don't get me wrong. You can do a lot with software and you don't need much hardware here. But details matter. And so a good balance to take OUT9 and operate the panel meter properly will take, I think, a lot more information from you than has been presented yet. You have done some testing to make sure that your software can operate OUT9. I've no doubt about that. So you know what you know. But we don't know what you know about what's behind OUT9. You need to pass along more of that, I think.

Answer (score 0):

From the [datasheet](https://assets.rs-online.com/v1700407226/Datasheets/b00f2e1055d464e6437610f3ee4f52df.pdf) it appears that the PWM output is a lowside switch. This means it pulls the load to ground so the other side of the load needs to be connected to a voltage.

To get 50 uA at 24 V you would calculate the current using Ohm's Law, R = E / I, so
$$
\frac{24 V}{50 uA} = 480k\Omega
$$
You might use something like a 470k and a 20k pot in series to give you a way to adjust it a bit (if you need more adjustment range use a lower value resistor and higher value pot where the total with the pot centered is around 480k), it would be connected like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsfm3F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your 24 V is not well regulated it could affect the reading, in which case you could regulate it down to a lower voltage for the meter circuit (since PWM is switching ground it shouldn't care what voltage the load is fed with) and recalculate the resistance.

Then there's the question of how the meter will react to PWM. If it's an analog meter the mechanical damping may be enough to smooth it out, or it may need to be low pass filtered to get a DC equivalent. This might be as simple as a capacitor across the meter, or it might require a more complicated circuit, possibly with op-amps.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your answer! So with that said, there's the question of resistor wattage. Since the load is 50uA at 24v, would it be safe to assume that a low wattage resistor would be sufficient for this application? Say, 1/4 or 1/2 watt? Is there any reason going with a resistor rated for a higher wattage might be bad for this application?

Comment: @JoeSchmo Wattage is current multiplied by voltage so it will be something in the milliwatt range, any resistor should do.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](https://barth-elektronik.com/downloads/9021-0025-C.pdf) it appears that the PWM output is pulled low for 'on'. It's not clear from the manual whether it's open drain/collector or whether it has a pullup to the supply. Since you've measured it, I'll assume there is a pullup.

So if the meter had zero internal resistance the required series resistor to get 50uA from 24V would be 480kΩ. So you could use a 430kΩ resistor in series with a 100kΩ trimpot connected as a rheostat.

So you'd connect it thusly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVLHnM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Be careful that a high resistance is always in series with the meter, it would be very easy to destroy or permanently damage it by connecting a voltage source directly across it.**  It may not be a good idea to try to measure the resistance directly either.

If your application has much vibration you may need to connect a capacitor across the meter to add damping. For this kind of panel meter application we often want to use a higher current meter such as 1mA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! The definitely clears things up for me!